# Time complexity difference in Linkedlist implementation (Iterative VS Recursive)?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

Does the time complexity change in these two implementation of getting the count of  nodes in a Linkedlist ?

```
 private int getCountIterative() {

    Node start = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (start != null)
    {
        count++;
        start = start.next;
    }
    return count;
}


private int getCountRecursive(Node node) {
    if (node == null)
        return 0;
    return 1 + getCountRecursive(node.next);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

No, the time complexity won't change.

However the performance and overall run time will usually be worse for recursive solution because Java doesn't perform [Tail Call Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization).

Comment: I am not sure that tail call optimization is possible here - the recursive call is not the last operation. One can rewrite the code to make it possible, though. Can an optimizer do that?

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR: it's the same complexitiy

To calculate the complexity of an operation (like a search or sort algorithm - or your example, the count), **you need to identify the dominating operation**.

For searching and sorting, it's usually comparisons. What is your dominating operation? Let's assume it's `node.next`, the lookup of the next node.

Then, both approaches have **O(n)** operations - so it's the same complexity.

Please be aware that this time complexity is a simplification. There are factors ignored, like the overhead of function calls. So, it's the same complexity, but that doesn't necessarily tell you which version is faster.